# React-native slider not saving current value, resets to default value not new value

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs, expo

So I have a component that updates all fields except the slider does not update it returns to default value instead. I need to keep the slider in place. The user presses an update button and the date and time update to current times but the slider reverts to a value of '5'.

I have tried playing with moment.js but the best I can get is that it will set the slider to a value of today. So instead of setting it to days until due it sets the value on update to todays date, so the slider value becomes 9 for August 9th, or 10 for August 10th.

````
    this.setState({ saving: true });
    greenhouse.grow_cycles[0].logs.push({
      type: log.type,
      value: null,
      user: userId,
      alert_interval: isMoment().AlertInterval,
      date_started: moment().toISOString(),
      date_due: moment().add(5, 'days').toISOString()
    });
    const res = await api.put(`/greenhouses/${greenhouse._id}`, greenhouse, token);
    if (res && !res.error) {
      await refresh();
      let index = 1;
      let actions = [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Greenhouse', params: { greenhouse: res.data } })
      ];
      const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index,
        actions,
      });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
      showToast(`New ${log.type} Log Added!`);
      this.setState({ saving: false });
    }
 else {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        reset();
      } else {
        showToast(res.error);
      }
      this.setState({ saving: false });
    }
}```
````

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you show me your code as a whole? Why do you run 'StackActions.reset'?

Comment: Okay, I was trying to avoid the entire component. On the action page for a greenhouse the user does things like water plants. There's a button that duplicates the action and creates a new event with date and time, but the slider - alert_interval - resets to a default value of 5 every time. The interval is important because the user needs to input when they need to check the plants again. It may not be 5 days, it may be 20 days or 7 days. I can't get the slider value set by the user to save.

Comment: I'm calling 'StackActions.reset' because we are creating a new instance of the activity that needs to be saved.

Comment: Where does the code change the value of the slider?

Comment: And reset has no props to pass parameters.

Comment: I think you should use redux to do what you want to do.

Comment: You're right I should use redux but the previous dev did not use redux. This is just straight up react-native.

Comment: There's this ```const DEFAULT_ALERT_INTERVAL = '5';``` in the Greenhouse.js model. '5' is the value it resets to when a duplicate task is created. But when I change that to a diff value it does not change the default value of the slider.

Comment: If you only want to change the slider value, you can change the value over the status value.

Comment: Is guess that's my question. I cannot figure out what to call.